# Swift Test: "error: cannot find in scope" when executing "swift test" command in CLI

Tags: swift, xctest

I'm facing an issue when executing the `swift test` command in my CLI.

The classes and structs tested inside my tests are not recognized when executing the command, whereas they're passing when they're executed using XCode interface. (*Image linked at the bottom of the post*)

Here's the `AppManager` file I want to test.

```swift
// AppManager.swift file
import Foundation
import Combine

public class AppManager {
    static let authenticated = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    
    static func isAuthenticated() -> Bool {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") != nil
    }
    
    static func getUser() -> User? {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "user") {
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let user = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
                
                return user
            } catch {
                print("Unable to Decode User (\(error))")
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    static func getUserToken() -> String? {
        if let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") {
            return token
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    static func getAppEnvironment() -> AppEnvironment {
        guard let savedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "selectedAppEnvironment"),
              let decodedEnvironment = try? JSONDecoder().decode(AppEnvironment.self, from: savedData)
        else {
            return .defaultEnv
        }
        
        return decodedEnvironment
    }
}
```

Here's its associated test file `AppManagerTests.swift`

```swift
// AppManagerTests.swift file
import XCTest

@testable import Tools

final class AppManagerTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Reset UserDefaults or set initial states here if necessary
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "token")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "user")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "selectedAppEnvironment")
    }
    
    func testIsUserAuthenticated() {
        XCTAssertFalse(AppManager.isAuthenticated())
        
        let randomToken = UUID().uuidString
        UserDefaults.standard.set(randomToken, forKey: "token")
        
        XCTAssertTrue(AppManager.isAuthenticated())
    }
    
    func testGetUser() {
        XCTAssertNil(AppManager.getUser())
        
        let user = User(firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", emailAddress: "john.doe@domain.com", roles: [User.UserRole.roleAdministrator], avatarImageUrl: "https://placehold.co/40", locale: "en")
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let userData = try? encoder.encode(user) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(userData, forKey: "user")
        }
        
        XCTAssertEqual(AppManager.getUser(), user)
    }
    
    func testGetAppEnvironment() {
        XCTAssertEqual(AppManager.getAppEnvironment(), AppEnvironment.defaultEnv)
        
        let environment = AppEnvironment.devEnv
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encodedData = try? encoder.encode(environment) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "selectedAppEnvironment")
        }
        
        XCTAssertEqual(AppManager.getAppEnvironment(), AppEnvironment.devEnv)
    }
    
    override class func tearDown() {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "token")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "user")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "selectedAppEnvironment")
    }

}
```

```swift
// Package.swift file
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Tools",
    products: [
        .executable(name: "Tools", targets: ["Tools"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies go here.
    ],
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "Tools",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ToolsTests",
            dependencies: ["Tools"],
            path: "ToolsTests"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ToolsUITests",
            dependencies: ["Tools"],
            path: "ToolsUITests")
    ]
)
```

I added both `Tools` and `ToolsTest` as Target Membership for `AppManager.swift`.

Do you have any idea about what I'm missing? Thank you

[Files and console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PndZW.jpg)

Comment: `swift test` probably requires a Swift Package to work and it certainly will not use any settings from the Xcode project file(s). Did you mean to run `xcodebuild`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry I forgot to mentioned that I have a Package.swift file. I updated my answer.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You are correct. `swift test` is targeted at packages. The poster should be using `xcodebuild`. I'm surprised `swift test` even finds the test source code.